# removing elements in a list with less than n

Tags: r

This is a simple question, how can I know which element in a numeric list is less than a *n* number, for example in this dummy example, how to get the elements with less than 5 elements?

```
list <- list(A=1:5, B=1, C=1:2, D=1, e=5:10)
```

The desired output will be the names of the elements (B,C, and D)

Thanks

Comment: [What, exactly, have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: take a look at the `apply` family of functions.  specifically `lappy` which will apply a function to each element of a list.  Sounds like you want the `length` function.  I also suggest spending a bit of time with a few of the R guides online to familiarize yourself with the language.

Comment: My mistake, `lapply(list, length)` works perfectly

Comment: From your question's title, you might also be interested in `Filter(function(x)length(x)>=5, list)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With what you have from the comments of Justin you are almost there. You can then use the `which` function to get the indices of each element in the list smaller than 5, together with the names. The function `names` gives you then the names:

```
names(which(lapply(list, length)<5))
```

Comment: Also just `names(list)[lengths(list) < 5]`